# What would you call a number that's 5 or 6 zeros past the decimal point?

Tags: numbers

Today the current price of the Shiba Inu CryptoCoin is listed as $0.0000017 USD.
How would you phrase this number?

Comment: six places is millionths. seventeen millionths. https://www.factmonster.com/math-science/mathematics/decimal-places

Comment: Do you want the mathematical terminology to refer to that exact number, or the math terminology to refer to numbers of that type, or in general how we refer to numbers so small it's almost meaningless?

Comment: @Lambie: I think it's actually 17 "tenths of a millionth" (or **1.7 millionths**).

Answer (score 2):

To read such numbers one usually reads digit by digit.

Exactly it is "zero point zero zero zero zero zero one seven dollars", or "zero point zero zero zero one seven cents".

You could also say it is "seventeen hundred-thousandths of a cent" or "seventeen ten-millionths of a dollar"  But beware because there is an ambiguity; "seventeen-hundred thousandths would be 1.700" (unlikely to be a real ambiguity, but it could cause confusion to someone)

Less exactly, it is "almost worthless".

Comment: have I counted the number of zeros right.  I'm going cross-eyed...

Comment: "Almost worthless" is good enough. If you wanted to inform someone of the value, you could say something like "600000 coins equal $1", or say "just over a millionth of a dollar" or any similar thing to give an inkling of the value.